# How to pull DIV row in bootstrap to right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have `DIV` that contains 2 `DIVs`, how to make the dives displayed from right to left using `CSS`

HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span3">Box 1</div>
   <div class="span9">Box 2</div>
</div>
```

now:

```
___________________________________
|       |                         |
| box 1 |       Box 2             |
|_______|_________________________|
```

I want to get this using CSS with same HTML code above:

```
___________________________________
|                        |        |
|        box 2           | Box 1  |
|________________________|________|
```

How is that ?

Comment: ^ Well, you might as well go ahead and add that to pretty much every single question currently tagged with "Boostrap" while you are at it.

Comment: Why are you using Bootstrap 2? It's months away from Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 2):

You can use the predefined class in bootstrap: `pull-left` and `pull-right`;

Example:

```
<div class="span3 pull-right">Box 1</div>
<div class="span9 pull-left">Box 2</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `.pull-right` class to box1 and `.pull-left` class to box2
For example...

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span3 pull-right">Box 1</div>
   <div class="span9 pull-left">Box 2</div>
</div>
```